# SQL for 1:1 match of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Given a table of two columns with recurring values in each column, how can I identify the rows where a 1:1 match between the two rows exists? E.g.

```
A A
B A
C A
A B
F B
C C
C C
B A
C A
```

I want to pick C C.

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to clarify your question by providing a table description and better sample data.  I am not sure how you derived "C C" from the the data you provided.

Comment: The rows in a database aren't ordered in a deterministic way. You might as well have selected "B A", because there's two of those...

Comment: Why do you choose C C only and not A A?

Comment: I think the OP means "non-unique rows", non?

Comment: Hm, can you better explain, what would you get? What means 1:1 match exists? Want you get B A/C A rows too?

Comment: Unique values in the first column match several rows in the second column - only C matches uniquely.

Comment: I think, I undesrtanf you B, match not F only here thats why it isn't showed?

Comment: Why will it show `C C` and not `B A` and `C A` as well?

Answer (score 3):

Group rows by `column1, column2` and pick those having `count > 1`

Comment: I can do this one column at a time - wanted a single SQL. For 1 column I have:select col1
                 from (select distinct col1,col2 
                         from tbl with (nolock)) a 
                     group by a.col1 having count(*) > 1)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

<strike>SELECT [COL1] , [COL2] FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [COL1] = 'C' AND [COL2] = 'C'</strike>

EDIT:

<strike>SELECT [COL1] , [COL2] FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [COL1] = [COL2]</strike>

EDIT 2:

So its a uniqueness thing then?

```
SELECT [COL1] , [COL2], COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [COL1] = [COL2] GROUP BY [COL1] , [COL2] HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: No: I do not know the values in the columns in advance.

Comment: Not quite - my fault as my example is not very good. Imagine column 1 contains Car Registration Number & Column 2 contains Make. The same car can go by several times - I want to select rows where the mapping of registration number and Make is 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate check, is it not? You want to find out any rows with duplicates on 2 columns?

So

```
select col1, col2 from table 
where exists(select 1 from table tab2 where table.col1=tab2.col1 
and table.col2=tab2.col2 and tab2.id <> table.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1,c2,count(*) as c FROM tbl GROUP BY c1 HAVING c=1
```

Comment: :With SQL Server 2000, I get: Column 'c2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: -- Column 1 does not match uniquely
`code`
  select col1
    from (select distinct col1,col2 
            from tbl with (nolock)) a 
group by a.col1 having count(*) > 1
`code`

-- Column 2 does not match uniquely

  select col2
    from (select distinct col1,col2 
            from tbl with (nolock)) a 
group by a.col2 having count(*) > 1


-- Need one query that returns the results of both (without using, say, union (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This? Its hard to understand exactly what your requirements are.

```
SELECT `COL1`, `COL2` FROM `TABLE` WHERE `COL1` = `COL2`
```